# How to return an existing column value from sharepoint to flow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, custom-list, form, flow

I am creating a flow using ms forms in which when an user submit a response with 'x' value it should fetch the corresponding column value for the [articular 'x'value both of which are already stored in a separate sharepoint list.
for example,if user submit the value 'sky' the corresponding column value for sky in sharepoint list is 'blue'so it should return value 'blue'to a new column on same or different list so that i can use that value on flow ,any workarounds please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Flow is not supported to loop all items.

A workaround: Suppose you created ListA and ListB, you added a new item in ListA with 'Sky' value and ListB stores 'Sky', 'Blue', shown as figure below.

[image]

1. Create a new column named "ColorA" in ListA.
2. Create a designer workflow in ListA, the workflow will loop through ListB items, get the corresponding Color value based on Things value of current item and set the ColorA column value when a new item is created in ListA.
3. Microsoft Flow can use the "ColorA" value in ListA.

By the way, you need to set the Flow be triggered when an item is modified.

Reference:
https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: I have tried using workflows,this issue with workflow is that the response is very slow and by the time i receive response from workflow my MS flow runs out.And i even tried delaying the MS flow but it is also not working out.